# How to Install and Enable XCRC on an Open-Source FTP Server in Debian 11?

Tags: ftp, proftpd, ftps

I'm currently working on Debian 11 and exploring options to enable and use the XCRC command for CRC32 checksums on an FTP server. Unfortunately, the instructions I've found for ProFTPD appear to be outdated, and the `mod_digest` package (or similar) is not available for Debian 11.

Given these challenges, I'm open to using an alternative open-source FTP server that supports XCRC. Could someone provide up-to-date guidance on installing and enabling XCRC on an open-source FTP server compatible with Debian 11? If ProFTPD is not the ideal choice, I'm willing to explore other options, so long as they are open source.

Any insights, recommendations, or pointers to current resources would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the mod_digest module is now included or bundled with ProFTPD by default, but it needs to be activated. To enable it, simply add the following line to the /etc/proftpd/modules.conf file:

```
LoadModule mod_digest.c
```

After adding this line, restart the ProFTPD server. Your FTP client should automatically recognize the new functionality.